# Using a button to draw on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been working on a interactive floorplan, that when you press a button, it would draw on the Canvas element. The more I have been working with this, the more I've grown aware that it might not even be possible - any ideas? Here's how much of the code I have done ( it does not work as intended, obviously)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="nav">
        <div id="buttons">
            <input type="button" id="clear" value="118">
        </div>
    </ul>
    <div id="main">
        <canvas id="118" width="1200" height="630" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas118");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
                context.moveTo(87,354);
                context.lineTo(169,426);
                context.lineTo(277,397);
                context.lineTo(198,324);
                context.lineTo(87,354);

                context.fillstyle = "#ff0000";
                context.fill();
                context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
                context.stroke();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the if condition u have here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code working / changed:
https://jsfiddle.net/dxhytwf4/2/

created a funcion and added the click event directly on the input:

```
<input type="button" id="clear" value="118" onclick="draw()" />
```

Javascript:

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("118");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ...
```

Also you were getting element canvas118 not 118

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you are missing the call to `beginPath()`...Try it like this:

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas118");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(300,150);
ctx.stroke();
```

Taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_moveto.asp).